# Working with a specific card RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I have a `RecyclerView` with many cards. Each card has a `TextView` (displayed immediately) and  `ImageView` (empty). How can I take the card I need (for example # 3 or # 13) and withdraw the img there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the logic in `onBindViewHolder` of your adapter class to change the visibility of the `imageView` to `gone` for the required position.